# Как получить ответ от сервера при AJAX запросе в случае ошибки (не 200)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net, iis

Есть метод на сервере, который должен вернуть файл для скачивания или ошибку (если файл не найден, например) с текстом.

Если файл существует и открывается, то все норм, а вот если нет, пользователю нужно вывести сообщение, которое возвращает сервер.

Когда я отправляю запрос средствами JQuery, то в функцию error приходит это сообщение

```
error: function(msg) {
    UserMessage.showMessage("Ошибка при загрузке документов!", msg.responseJSON, "danger");
}
```

Но JQUery мне не подходит, потому что мне надо остановить запрос, когда readyState == 2, а в JQuery я такой возможности не нашел. Есть только success.

Поэтому использую нативный XMLHttpRequest. Но проблема в том, что я не знаю как в данном случае достать это сообщение от сервера. Я просто не могу его найти. Я даже через Restlet client пробовал отправлять этот запрос, но получаю только статус ошибки, а того сообщения, которое отправляет сервер, просто нигде нет. Магия какая-то.

Comment: Если это ошибка, генерируемая вашим скриптом, то я бы посоветовал JSONом отправлять объект, в котором есть свойство `error`, например, и затем в `success` проверять наличие этого свойства и выводить ошибку, а XML ошибки оставить всяким техническим неполадкам. Это, конечно, не решение вашего вопроса, я ответа не знаю и просто рассуждаю вслух.

Comment: @Diskyp, Править сервер я буду в крайнем случае. Он же работает корректно.

Comment: @diproart, кода ошибки недостаточно. Если с сервера приходит 404, хотелось бы еще знать, почему.

Comment: @diproart, нет не прикол. Я в вопросе написал, что сервер возвращает статус с текстом.

Comment: @diproart, увы, в заголовках этого нет :(  Я же говорю, я даже через restlet client в хроме отправляю запрос, вижу весь ответ в удобном виде и там нет нужного мне текста с описанием. Поэтому откуда он берется, если запрос отправлять через JQuery.ajax я не понимаю.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

В общем я перепробовал много всего, пробовал менять responseType, другие параметры запроса. В итоге, детально сравнив заголовки отправки запроса, формируемого JQuery и нативным XMLHttpRequest, я обнаружил, что в нативном запросе отсутствует header

> X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest

Без него в ответ вместо сообщения, отправляемого сервером, приходила стандартная браузерная HTML страничка с кодом ошибки и описанием.

Решение для меня было совсем не очевидным, поэтому надеюсь, что это будет кому-то полезным.

Comment: @diproart, не так. Сервер возвращает сообщение в боди ответа. Это все, что требуется знать, остальное - абстракции

Comment: @diproat, то есть вы считаете, что разработчик, который будет ковырять ajax запросы не может на это намотаться и мой случай - случайность?

Comment: @diproart, заголовок не влияет на ответ сервера в данном случае. Это браузерная фича

Comment: Все это относиться к конкретной реализации и не более. Заголовок  `X-Requested-With` не является стандартом. Его использование регламентируется требованиями API или реализацией сервера. Пожалуйста помните это.  @iRumba - "ковырять", "намотаться" и "браузерная фича"  это хорошо, но вы так и не ответили не на один вопрос. **А было интересно понять - куда, на какой сервер, фреймворк, вы отправляете запрос**. У вас заработало, я рад. Но это не ответ, в вопросе одно, в ответе другое. Можно было просто сказать - к серверу нет доступа или документации по нему.

Comment: X-Requested-With - нужен именно для того, чтобы сообщить серверу, что мы используем AJAX. Но сервер должен "уметь" это учитывать. Сервер отвечает на запросы!

Comment: @diproart, то есть вы отите сказать, что с сервера отправляется не то сообщение, которое ему "приказали отправить", а Html страница, очень похожая на стандартную страницу гугл хрома при подобных ошибках?

Comment: Сервер сам решает, ему нельзя приказать, мы отправляем "пожелание", но  что отправлять, решает сервер. Заголовки - это соглашения, инструкции, но не приказы. Под сервером в данном  случае мы понимаем приложение. AJAX запрос можно отправить куда угодно. С сервера приходит ответ на основе параметров запроса/заголовков и т.д. Если сервер "не понимает" заголовка "X-Requested-With" или не может ответить как JSON, то придет стандартная страница.  Приложение/Сервер должен уметь отвечать на такие запросы. Один может, а другой нет.

Comment: @diproart, я не нашел никакого упоминания про этот заголовок для моего приложения (ASP.NET). Поэтому я не могу быть уверенным в том, кто обрабатывает этот заголовок, сервер или браузер (не клиентский скрипт, а именно браузер). Раз так, я не мог ничего написать про это в ответе. Поэтому просто написал, что возникла проблема, когда сообщение от сервера не приходило, при том, что мой код выполнялся корректно, и предложил решение данной проблемы. Возможно, у кого-нибудь будет такая же проблема, сервер будет не ASP.NET, и решение окажется подходящим.

Comment: Так я об этом и говорю, что чем понятнее контекст - тем полезнее вопрос/ответ. Это сразу сужает область применения. Просто упоминание об ASP.NET уже супер. Спасибо.

Comment: @diproart, но в данном случае это может запутать, потому что, как вы сказали, сервер может "уметь", а может "не уметь". Что, если дело не в приложении, а в сервисе IIS (в моем случае IIS express)? А что, если обработка данного заголовка задается в какой нибудь настройке? Проблему то я в итоге решил на клиенте, про сервер я вообще мог ничего не знать.

Comment: @diproart, в итоге поиск решения свелся к сравнению заголовков, отправляемых $.ajax и нативным AJAX. И если убрать из ответа лишнее, получится так. Если сервер в ответ на запрос $.ajax присылает ответ, а в ответ на идентичный запрос AJAX присылает пустоту, попробуйте добавить заголовок.... И все. Без всяких там отсылок к серверному приложению. Проблема решается на клиенте. Сервер - абстракция

Comment: Ходим по кругу) Не могу согласиться, потому-что, так можно, "что хочешь сравнивать и подставлять", но **думаю наш с вами диалог, "хорошее" дополнение к вопросу**. В комментариях уже более понятные рассуждения и полезные (хоть часть комментариев и пришлось удалить).